# momentjs deprecation warning

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am using momentjs to format my dates and came across an odd warning:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

The link to the warning implies that my date is not in a valid format. Here is my code:

`let thisDate = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")`

The date returned from `new Date()` in a format supported by momentjs, according to its documentation... Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pro-tip: If you're trying to create a value for *now*, you don't need to pass anything. `let thisDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')` would work just fine.

Comment: Please note that `moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")` does **not** print _Deprecation warning_ (at least using recent version of moment). I think that the issue is elsewhere in your code and it could be solved using [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) as explained in the suggested duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
let thisDate = moment(new Date().toISOString()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

or better

```
let thisDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Explication :

```
new Date()
```

`Thu Oct 19 2017 17:50:06 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))`
==> depending of local browser and **browser implementation**

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

`"2017-10-19T15:50:31.690Z"`
==> fixed format, it's always safe ! ;-)

Comment: `moment(new Date().toISOString()).format(...)` creates a date, converts it to a string, passes it to *moment*, where it is parsed back to a Date again, then formatted.

Comment: I agreee, this is why I have indicated the better solution is : `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')`